# Python Bot for Browsergame- I need some help fixing this please

Tags: python, bots

I have a Bot for the browsergame "Dragoncave". My problem is, that I have no idea how to tell it to go from the index to one of the 5 biomes (see yourself: http://dragcave.net).

This is what I have:

```
import httplib, urllib

def login(): 
   id= raw_input("Please enter the cookie for scroll dragon[id]:")
   passw = raw_input("Please enter the cookie for pass (dragon[pass]:")
   return [id,passw]

def followLink(link,cookie): 
   con = httplib.HTTPConnection('dragcave.net/',80,timeout=2)
   con.putrequest('GET', link)
   con.putheader('Cookie', 'dragon[id]=' + cookie[0] +'; ' +'dragon[pass]=' + cookie[1] + '
check=1; referers=1; initjs=1; ads=0; pc=1; uc=0; ff=1;  _utma=164703850.337915616.1288510222.1288564452.1288567367.9');  
   con.putheader('Referer', 'http://dragcave.net/')
   con.putheader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12')
   con.endheaders()
   return con.getresponse()

def getData(cookie):     
   con = httplib.HTTPConnection('dragcave.net/',80,timeout=2)
   con.putrequest('GET', '/')
   con.putheader('Cookie', 'dragon[id]=' + cookie[0] +';' +'dragon[pass]=' + cookie[1])
   con.putheader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20091221 Firefox/3.5.7')
   con.endheaders()
   response = con.getresponse()
   data = response.read()
   links = []
   texts = []
   links.append(data[data.index('/get'):data.index('/get') + 9])
   data = data[data.index('/get'):len(data)]
   texts.append(data[data.index('<br/>')+5:data.index('</div>')])
   data = data[data.index('</div>'):len(data)]
   links.append(data[data.index('/get'):data.index('/get') + 9])
   data = data[data.index('/get'):len(data)]
   texts.append(data[data.index('<br/>')+5:data.index('</div>')])
   data = data[data.index('</div>'):len(data)]
   links.append(data[data.index('/get'):data.index('/get') + 9])
   data = data[data.index('/get'):len(data)]
   texts.append(data[data.index('<br/>')+5:data.index('</div>')])
   data = data[data.index('</div>'):len(data)]
   con.close()
   return {texts[0]:links[0],texts[1]:links[1],texts[2]:links[2]}
```

**and**

```
import Autodragon,time,sys;
import webbrowser
dragon = raw_input("Enter the dragon codes. Put a #inbetween:").split("#")
location= raw_input("Enter the name of the locations. Put a #inbetween:").split("#")
cookie = Autodragon.login()
while 1:     
    try: 
        data = Autodragon.getData(cookie)
        print "Refresh"
        for d in dragon: 
            for t in data: 
                if  d == t: 
                    Autodragon.followLink(data[t], cookie)
                    webbrowser.open_new_tab("about:" + data[t][5:])
                    print d + " found"
    except:  
        exceptionType, exceptionValue, exceptionTraceback = sys.exc_info()
        print exceptionType;    <br/>
        print exceptionValue
        print exceptionTraceback
        time.sleep(2)
```

Can anybody help me fix this please? And I am sorry for not being able to list the text the way it should be D: Hope it is understandable anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do something called screen scraping. There are libraries for that, one of the most popular is called [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Try looking at the documentation and follow some examples there. You will have a much more enjoyable time.

Comment: Thank you, I shall try it out, I have BeautifulSoup already I just need to find out how to work it as I am still right at the beginning of learning python^^